# Drop-down menu inside list elements expand list size and are hard to access

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div which contains a list. This list contains multiple drop-down elements. When the drop-down elements towards the bottom of the list are selected, the list expands in size to accommodate for these new elements. However, these elements are also hidden unless the user scrolls down to click on them. The preferred solution would be having the drop-down elements appear above all others on the list. However, attempting to do this through z-indexing and absolute/relative positioning doesn't appear to work no matter what combination I attempt. Is there any fix to this problem that I am missing?

NOTE: Best simulated when in full screen.

```css
    /*CSS borrowed from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown_hover*/
    .dropbtn {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
        padding: 16px;
        font-size: 16px;
        border: none;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        min-width: 160px;
        z-index: 100;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd}
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
        background-color: #3e8e41;
    }
    
    /* Other random CSS */
    
    .background {
      height : 500px;
      width  : 800px;
      background-color: #d47500
    }
    
    .list-holder{
      height : 300px;
      overflow-y : auto;
      background-color: #b2815b
    }
```

```html
    <div class="background">
    
      <div class="list-holder">
      
        <ul>
        
          <li>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
              <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          
          <li>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
              <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          
          <li>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
              <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          
          <li>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
              <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          
    <!-- Problem -->
          <li>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
              <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
      
      <!-- Problem -->
          <li>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
              <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          
      <!-- Problem -->
          <li>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
              <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        
        </ul>
      
      
      </div>
      
    </div>
```

A solution I am considering is using javascript to generate a similar drop-down menu above all the other divs. Unfortunately, I am not sure on how to begin doing this. If anyone has any ideas on how, please let me know.

EDITS:

- A fixed list size is mandatory for this implementation.

Answer (score 0):

`absolute` positioning and `z-index`s won't help if you have `overflow-y: auto` and an explicit height set on the nav's parent container. If you remove those it behaves how you would like, example:

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    z-index: 100;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.background {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #d47500
}

.list-holder{
  position: relative;
  background-color: #b2815b
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="list-holder">
  
    <ul>
    
      <li>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
  
      <li>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    
    </ul>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate your solution, but unfortunately that doesn't work for me. A fixed size is mandatory in my scenario. Otherwise the page itself is expanded and is no longer visually appealing/easy to use.